# need to get offset of struct data member

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, visual-studio-2015

I have a member of an object defined as:

```
struct statebuf
{
  void* sp;
  void* label;
};
```

in my asm code I do:

```
#define restorestate(SSB)   \
  __asm mov ebx, this       \
  __asm mov esp, [ebx]SSB.sp\
  __asm jmp [ebx]SSB.label
#endif
```

I use the macro like a function. After the "mov ebx, this" I need to add an offset to ebx to hit the right member. How can I obtain the offset for SSB?

Comment: No sure if you want this method in c++ or in assembler, but in c++ you can use `offsetof`. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/offsetof/

Comment: C++ has an `offsetof` function/operator.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```
#define restorestate(SSB)   \
  __asm mov ebx, this       \
  __asm add ebx, [SSB]      \
  __asm mov esp, [ebx]SSB.sp\
  __asm jmp [ebx]SSB.label
#endif
```

Which I got from trial and error.